# DSOFile is not working in Office 2013 to add custom properties

Tags: office-2013, custom-properties, dsofile

We were successfully working with office files using DSOFile.dll to add custom properties into the files. After entering into the Office 2013, DSO stops working. We tried creating POCs in the same environment as follows and that too not working. Below is the code snippet for adding custom properties.

```
            OleDocumentPropertiesClass doc = new OleDocumentPropertiesClass();
            doc.Open(fileName, false, dsoFileOpenOptions.dsoOptionOpenReadOnlyIfNoWriteAccess);
            object val = "joy";
            doc.CustomProperties.Add("joyskeyclass", ref val);
            doc.Save();
```

We can read the custom properties added to office 2013 files using DSOFile.dll. But its not listed when we open in the office apps like excel and navigate to custom properties dialog. Also if we add custom properties via MS word custom dialog properties its not listed down during iteration in DSO objects.

Comment: The environement we are using is Win 7 64bit. I could see that ,for proper functioning of DSOFile we need to have msoshext.dll available in MS Office which is not coming by default.For office 2010 and 2007 there were hotfixes. But could not see one for Office 2013.According to MSFT it is scheduled for first quarter of 2013. But how to confirm whether that is released? Below is the link to the same...http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officegeneral/thread/ca237b65-ee51-4a49-ae26-7e0b6f93c5f9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this worked after installing latest office 2013 patches.

Especially the MsoShExt.dll came via

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2760502